# AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'setblocking'

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonblocking

I'm trying to use 'non-blocked socket' for a Python project

(see previous question if anyone has a better answer : [How to use a socket without waiting in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68791172/how-to-use-a-socket-without-waiting-in-python) )

I saw that people on the site suggested using the command:
`socket.setblocking ()`

But when I run the program it crashes, and the error is recorded:

```
 AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'setblocking'
```

How can I fix this?

And is there another way?

Comment: which python version you are using?

Comment: check this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html  "Changed in version 3.7: The method no longer applies SOCK_NONBLOCK flag on socket.type. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call `setblocking()` on the *module* called [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) rather than on the *object* called [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket).

Change your code to something like:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(...)

s.setblocking(...)
```

Comment: Thanks.
Good answer, but the code does not match what I need :-\
I'm looking for code that can not delay the program at all, as well as create communication.
I will continue to search ...